# Material UI cannot pop up dialog with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am learning the material ui and i am testing a few examples of the dialog. What I want is a popup dialog that contains two textfields: login and password, and two buttons: submit and cancel.

with the code below, il compiled but I cannot pop up the dialog when clicking the button "DIALOG". there are 2 errors:

[image: errors before clicking button]

DialogSimple.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import RaiseButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextFieldLogin from './TextFieldLogin';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

export default class DialogSimple extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: true};
    injectTapEventPlugin();
  }


  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
  };   

  render() {

    const actions = [
      <div>
      <TextFieldLogin />
      <RaiseButton
        label="Annuler"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <RaiseButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      </div>
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <RaiseButton label="Dialog"  onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}/>
        <Dialog
          title="login"
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >
        login
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

TextFieldLogin.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const TextFieldLogin = () => (
  <div>
    <h3>Veuillez login</h3>
    <TextField
      hintText="Votre login"
      floatingLabelText="Login"
    /><br />
    <TextField
      hintText="Votre mot de passe"
      type="password"
      floatingLabelText="Password"
    /><br />
  </div>
);

export default TextFieldLogin;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import DialogSimple from './DialogSimple'

const App = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <DialogSimple/>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

After I clicked the button"DIALOG", it becomes black and creates more errors:

[image]

I tried react-tap-event-plugin but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Its always better if you copy paste the error rather than taking a screenshot.

Comment: try this: instead of instantiating `injectTapEventPlugin();` inside `Dialog` component, do that in `App` component, at the top. and remove the import also from Dialog component.

Comment: I just tried, unluckily it didn't change anything, still the same errors.